# Excel count based on multiple columns

Tags: excel

How to lookup matching values on multiple columns on excel and return its count?

I've already tried pivot table but it does not satisfy my requirement. The data returned by pivot table is in a different format and also I need to insert the count values as a column in another sheet.[image]

Hope this image gives clarity on what i am looking for. Here I have two tables. I have to lookup the count of univ and course(columns E and F) from columns B and C and return the count value in Column G

Comment: Looks like what you need is [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842)

Comment: I removed the `dax` tag - as I don't see how it is relevant, if this is in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,"="&E2,$C$2:$C$8,"="&F2)
```